# Usage of 'much more'

Tags: grammar, word-usage, colloquialisms, comparatives

Is saying *much more* grammatically correct? 
For instance, some purists argue that this is wrong:

> I'm much more comfortable with A than B

and that it should be:

> I'm more comfortable with A than B

or, to emphasize:

> I'm a lot more comfortable with A than B

*Much more* does sound colloquial but I've seen it used in newspapers and articles so I was curious.

Comment: _More_ is the comparative of _much_.

Comment: btw, that should probably be "with A than *with* B"

Comment: My parents bought me up to believe "much more" was bad grammar.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Much more* is perfectly grammatical, and in fact much more popular than *a lot more*, according to both the [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) and the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](http://www.americancorpus.org/):

```
                         BNC   COCA

much more               8024  29549
a lot more              1209   9954 
much more comfortable     28    203
a lot more comfortable    12     72
much more expensive       47    186
a lot more expensive      13     47
```

*Much more comfortable* is more popular in all contexts, from spoken to academic. In fact, in academic contexts it is preferred by a significantly larger margin than in speech:

```
                        SPOKEN  FICTION  MAGAZINE  NEWSPAPER  ACADEMIC

much more comfortable    0.65     0.26     0.73      0.51       0.22
a lot more comfortable   0.33     0.06     0.21      0.22       0.02
```

<sup>(Average number of occurrences per million words.)</sup>

Comment: I would always consider "a lot" to be informal, while "much more" is normal in all registers.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I am much more inclined to use this much more of the time, than any other colloquial phrase that has much less importance.

Answer (score -1):

I'd say it's fine. There may be some words where adding `much` is not correct but I can't think of them. (I'm thinking of overspecifications like `more unique`, but applying to the adverb.)

Answer (score -2):

*Again and again* is in usage like *much more*.  The sense differs when only one  adjective is used.